# Why does the != operator not call my '__neq__' method?

Tags: python, methods, comparison-operators

I tried to implement some wildcard class that compares equal to any string, but false to anything else. However, the `!=` operator does not appear to call my `__neq__` member as expected:

```
class A(str):
    def __cmp__(self, o):
        return 0 if isinstance(o, str) else -1

    def __eq__(self, o):
        return self.__cmp__(o) == 0

    def __neq__(self, o):
        return self.__cmp__(o) != 0

a = A()
b = 'a'
print(a == b) # Prints True, as expected
print(a != b) # Prints True, should print False
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is a typo question...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It’s an interesting typo. It’s the sort of typo someone familiar with Windows batch files would make where `!=` is spelled `NEQ`.  Or the it’s the memory mistake one would make by blending `__ne__` with `__eq__`.   So the error is more one of the mind than of the fingers.  I agree with closing it, but people’s  downvotes were unfortunate. It was was a well structured question.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski interesting indeed: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1459

Comment: I have voted to reopen. The answer is enough, but I wouldn't like to see this question closed or deleted now, I found a lot of answers with that `__neq__` mistake

Comment: Worth a downvote for no research, though. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) The answer, *"A lot. An absurd amount. More than you think you are capable of. After you have reached the end of your rope and the pain of not having the answer exceeds the vast amount of shame received by posting your question, that's when you can go ahead and ask. Because at that point, you will have done whatever research necessary to make it a good question worth asking!"*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For overriding the `!=` you need to define [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) but you defined `__neq__`.

So you have to change

```
def __neq__(self, o):
```

to

```
def __ne__(self, o):
```

Comment: Thanks! It was a stupid mistake, but I would never have caught it!